# deploying contract in the test net

Tags: blockchain, solidity, smartcontracts

[Injected provider option is not working, how can I connect my metamask wallet and deploy my contract](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vyHmD.png)

[I tried to look for the similar environment as in the yt but wasn't able to find one so I selected the Injected provider-Metamask option but it isn't responding, do i need to have real eth to deploy on ht e test net cuz this is my first contract and to deploy it on the test net do i need eth ??](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5IoHC.png)

Comment: Yes, you need eth to pay for the gas fees for the transaction. You can request free eth from [a faucet](https://ethereum.org/en/developers/docs/networks/#:~:text=The%20two%20public%20testnets%20that,lets%20stakers%20test%20running%20validators.). Make sure you're on the right network, and provide your public address.

Answer (score 0):

If you will select MetaMask it will automatically connect to the mainnet. If you want to use any testnet like goerli, then you need to select Goerli from the metamask dropdown for switching networks.[remix/metamask ss](https://i.stack.imgur.com/91moV.png)